# Ubuntu does not start "no bootable device"

Tags: boot, boot-repair

Ubuntu does not start in an [acer e5-551](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/5415;-;Aspire%20E5-551) laptop and when I turn it on, a message appears that says "no bootable device"

I have used the boot repair tool from a USB but the recommended repair does not appear so I created a bootinfo summary.

This is the link.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hZZYdrB2bH/

UPDATE 1:

Using the testdisk tool I have obtained the following information:

[partitions can't be recovered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Gty.jpg)

[partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foIVg.jpg)

I have listed the files of the partitions and I have been able to confirm the following:

- The HPFS - NTFS partition corresponds to the Windows partition.
- The Linux partition corresponds to the Ubuntu partition.

I understand that now before doing anything the first thing is to try to recover the files and once recovered try to restore the partitions.

I wanted to check with you before proceeding.

Comment: 1) Did it ever boot after first installation? 2) Which version of Ubuntu was installed? 3) Is Legacy Boot enabled in the BIOS/firmware 4) Is Secure Boot enabled in the BIOS/firmware? 5) Is Fast Boot enabled in the BIOS/firmware? Please click [edit] and add the answers to 1-5 into your question. Please don't put them in Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: Did computer freeze up during install(intel baytrail bug)?

Comment: Your partition table is totally corrupt. Since MBR you do not have a backup on drive like gpt does. Do you know or have backup of partition table structure  anywhere? You might try testdisk. You may just have to re-install & restore from backups. https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu & http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step